# Display link font face in same color as the surrounding face

Tags: faces, hyperlinks

I'd like to remove `:foreground` color specificity from `link` face so that it displays in the same color as the surrounding face. For example, in the below image, "link" should be brown and "Advanced reactor types" should be white. How to do this?

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
  'user
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:foreground "systemTealColor" :height 1.15))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:foreground "systemBrownColor"))))
  '(link ((t (:weight normal :underline "grey37")))))
```

[image]

Comment: `C-u C-x =` with point on the link text tells you what face(s) to customize (near the bottom). You can customize that face to just `:inherit` from the `default` face (or any other face).

Comment: It depends on how the text is rendered in the buffer. If the text contains *both* the `link` and `org-level-1` faces, using a `link` face without a `:fourground` properly should work. If you only have `link` then you should fix the font-lock rules -- the `OVERRIDE` flag should be `append` and not `t` which way too many people use.